# How to simulate errors against DynamoDB in Go?

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

How does one simulate errors against DynamoDB using Go? This blog post only talks about Java... https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/injecting-failures-and-latency-using-the-aws-sdk-for-java/

Answer (score 3):

```
import (
   errors "golang.org/x/xerrors"
)

client := dynamodb.New(sess)
client.Handlers.Validate.AfterEachFn = func(item request.HandlerListRunItem) bool {
    item.Request.Error = errors.New("simulated error")
    return false
}
```

Comment: Instant answer :thinking_face: :D. Does this work?

Comment: @slackmart yes, I wanted to document it somewhere